# Quadratic extensions under $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

What are some subfields, $F$ (besides $\mathbb{R}$), with $F\subset \mathbb{C}$ such that $\mathbb{C}/F$ has degree 2?  How can I show there are infinitely many?  Can I explicitly construct some of them?

Comment: You need Zorn's Lemma to create such things...

Comment: Given any automorphism $\sigma$ of $\mathbb C$ that does not fix $\mathbb R$, the fixed field of $\sigma$ does what you ask for.  Construct such an automorphism by transfinite recursion, or (as Stark said) Zorn's Lemma.

Comment: @GEdgar I have a vague idea of the construction youre talking about, but i have some doubts:  so i pick a transcendence basis for R over Q and one for C over Q and I just map the former to the latter in any way i want, and then that extends to an *endomorphism* of C, right?  I'm not so clear on why thats an *automorphism,* for instance.

Comment: That is, I know there are infinitely many copies of R in C, but why those imbeddings are also degree 2 under C is not so clear to me, just from that construction.  i'm probably doing it wrong, so if you could be more explicit about the construction that might help

Comment: also do you mean $\sigma$ to be an involution (otherwise the fixed field may have larger degree under C)? as it happens this question arose because i was trying to prove there are infinitely many involutions of C